# Google Sheet Column Tick box validation

Tags: google-sheets-query

Complete newbie here, sorry if this sounds silly.

I have 3 columns and 60 rows of tick boxes, I have the tick boxes adding up at the bottom of the sheet.

Question is I do not want a user to tick more than the available ticks per column each column has a maximum amount of tick boxes available.

For example column, A max ticks allowed is 12, B max ticks allowed 7 and C Max 25.